# Why is this LinearLayout not matching the parent?

Tags: android, xml, button, layout, android-linearlayout

I tried to create a soundboard with two columns of buttons, also I want to Scroll it.

This is my XML:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:onClick="button"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:text="button"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="20dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight = "1"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
                android:onClick="button1"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="button1"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="20dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight = "1"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
                android:onClick="button2"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:text="button2"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="20dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight = "1"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
                android:onClick="button3"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="button3"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="20dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button4"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:onClick="button4"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:text="button4"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="20dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button5"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight = "1"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
                android:onClick="button5"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="button5"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="20dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button6"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:onClick="button6"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:text="button6"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="20dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button7"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight = "1"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
                android:onClick="button7"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="button7"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="20dp" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

But I'm getting this result: https://gyazo.com/f7b60acbdb68c1de3faad3f96b5b8749

The LinearLayout is not matching the parent, it fills only the half of the screen.

How can I set the LinearLayout that it matches the whole parent?

My second question is, if I'm going to add 100 more rows, will this Scrollview doing his job? How can I do it that I can scroll through the 100 rows?

P.S I'm new at Android Studio, sorry for my small knowledge.

Comment: If you want tto scroll through hundreds (or even more than just a few) rows, then you need to look into ListView, GridView, or RecyclerView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true">
```

This should fix the issue if you are only dealing with 1 activity and a layout. If you are having multiple fragments and each have different sizes, that can be a different story.

---

Use RecyclerView or GridView instead of hardcoding 100 lines. That's a better solution